# Change the font size in a text layer

Tags: photoshop-script

I'm trying to create a script for Photoshop, but all my text gets the same size. I've created a small test script that shows my problem. Both layers get the same text size, and the size doesn't make sense.

```
var DPI = 300
$.writeln(DPI + " DPI **********************************");

//UnitValue.baseUnit = UnitValue(1/DPI, "in");
//$.writeln("baseUnit: " + UnitValue.baseUnit);

doc = app.documents.add(
    200, 
    287, 
    DPI, 
    "Test");
var layer = doc.artLayers.add();
layer.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;
layer.textItem.font = "PalatinoLinotype-Roman";
layer.textItem.size = new UnitValue(3,  "mm");
$.writeln("textItem.size: " + layer.textItem.size + " (" + layer.textItem.size.baseUnit + ")");

var layer2 = doc.artLayers.add();
layer2.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;
layer2.textItem.font = "PalatinoLinotype-Roman";
layer2.textItem.size = new UnitValue(120,  "px");
$.writeln("textItem.size: " + layer2.textItem.size + " (" + layer2.textItem.size.baseUnit + ")");
```

This is what it looks like when I run it in the ExtendScript Toolkit:

[image]

I'm new to this, so am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Running your script under CS4 does not produce these results.I get `textItem.size: 8.50393707275391 pt (0.00333333333333 in)`
`textItem.size: 120 pt (0.00333333333333 in)`

Comment: However people are having success under CC using the same technique. I would advise to try and change the size of an existing text layer that you manually create in PS to help sort out what's going wrong in your setup. Get an existing layer using: `app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("My text")`

Comment: I tried to install CC (I was running CC 2014), and there everything works as expected. Looks like a bug with CC 2014 :-(